# How do I get the file path of a file saved using write.xlsx or another function in R?

Tags: r, excel, rstudio

I am creating two dataframes and one graph on Rstudio. I wrote code to transfer them to an Excel file on different sheets, but each time I have to choose the file path using file.choose(). Is it possible to assign the file path to the variable when saving the file for the first time? If such a method exists, how can it be done?

I would also like to receive comments on how to more easily export my dataframes to an excel file. I shared my codes.

Thank you to everyone.

```
dataframe1 <- data.frame("A"=1, "B"=2)
dataframe2 <- data.frame("C"=3,"D"=4)

list_of_datasets <- list("Name of DataSheet1" = dataframe1, "Name of Datasheet2" = dataframe2, )
write.xlsx(list_of_datasets, file = "writeXLSX2.xlsx")

dflist <- list("Sonuçlar"=yazılacakdosya0, "Frame"=dtf, "Grafik"="")
edc <- write.xlsx(dflist, file.choose(new = T), colNames = TRUE,
                  borders = "surrounding",
                  firstRow = T,
                  headerStyle = hs)
require(ggplot2)
q1 <- qplot(hist(yazılacakdosya0$Puan))
print(q1)
insertPlot(wb=edc, sheet = "Grafik")
saveWorkbook(edc, file = file.choose(), overwrite = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just save the file path *before* you call `saveWorkbook`

```
file = file.choose()
saveWorkbook(edc, file = file, overwrite = T)
```

Comment: the user will choose where to save the file.  the user will also make the file naming.  I want that user select the file path only once and at this point I want to assign the file path to the variable. That mean after saving file.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to save the file before the user decides where to save it? In my code, the user decides and it i immediately saved at the place of the users choice.

Comment: what I really want is this;  exporting two dataframe and one graphic(histogram) to excel file(3 seperate sheet) at one time